# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre afterValidate y beforeCreate en Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sailsjs

Según lo que tengo entendido
`afterValidate` ocurre después de que el modelo haya sido validado, para después ser creado y `beforeCreate` ocurre antes de crear, entonces no comprendo cual es la diferencia entre cada uno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una diferencia: `beforeCreate` se llama sólo en el proceso de creación (antes del `create`); mientras que `afterValidate` se llama tanto en el proceso de creación como en el de actualización ([fuente](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks) traducida del inglés):

> **Llamadas al crear**
>
> - beforeValidate: fn(valores, cb)
> - afterValidate: fn(valores, cb)
> - beforeCreate: fn(valores, cb)
> - afterCreate: fn(registroRecienInsertado, cb)
>
> **Llamadas al actualizar**
>
> - beforeValidate: fn(valoresActualizacion, cb)
> - afterValidate: fn(valoresActualizacion, cb)
> - beforeUpdate: fn(valoresActualizacion, cb)
> - afterUpdate: fn(registroActualizado, cb)

Si defines `afterValidate` se ejecutará antes de crear o actualizar, mientras que `beforeCreate` se llamará antes de crear pero no de actualizar. Por lo que podría ser conveniente usar `afterValidate` en lugar de duplicar código en `beforeCreate` y `beforeUpdate`.